# Error is "Mcrypt extention not loaded" while running project and using WAMP server

Tags: php, wampserver

i am using wamp server. I am trying to run existing php project. But one of its form is giving error as "Mcrypt extention not loaded" while loading. My php.ini file is having entry as "extension=php_mcrypt.dll". Then too its giving me same error. So what i need to do to remove this error. Please can someone help me.

Comment: Did you check using `phpinfo()` if it is loaded?

Comment: **Did you restart Apache?** Also, make a web page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and look at the output to see if `mcrypt` is listed.

Comment: @Hanky Panky: ya sir i checked it using phpinfo(),but its not showing mcrypt

Comment: @AmalMurali: Ya sir i restarted wamp server. And also checked with phpinfo(),but its not showing mcrypt

Comment: @user1722857: Make sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. Check the path using `phpinfo()` and edit *that* `php.ini` file.

Comment: @user1722857 What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: make sure you set the path in the php.ini file mcrypt.algorithms_dir=/usr/local/lib/libmcrypt and mcrypt.modes_dir=/usr/local/lib/libmcrypt